Confusing behavior in training with tf.py_function. Broadcastable shapes error at random batch and epoch
I am training using a training loop over tensorflow dataset. However the training stops at an arbitrary batch number, different one each time
The loop trains for a while, but gives an error at an arbitrary batch and epoch, different everytime. The exact error  I get is
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Mul_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} required broadcastable shapes [Op:Mul] name: 

which suggests the shapes of the inputs and targets are not being respected through the  data pipeline. I use the following structure to create a data pipeline
data_pipeline(idx):
x = data[idx] #read in a given element of a numpy array
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
## Perform various manipulations

return x1, x2 #x1 with shape ([240, 132, 1, 2]), x2 with shape ([4086, 2])

def tf_data_pipeline(idx):
    [x1,x2] = tf.py_function(func=data_pipeline, inp=[idx], Tout=[tf.float32,tf.float32])
    
    x1 = tf.ensure_shape(x1, [240, 132, 1, 2])
    x2 = tf.ensure_shape(x2, [4086, 2])
    
    return x1,x2

I then set up the tf.Dataset
batch_size = 32
train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((range(32*800)))
train = train.map(tf_data_pipeline)
train = train.batch(batch_size)

Then I set up a traning loop over the tf.Dataset
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = model(x_batch_train)
            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, y_pred) 
            
        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, dcunet8.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        dcunet8.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, dcunet8.trainable_weights))

The actual failure is happening in the tape.gradient step
Note that I have a custom loss function but I don't think the problem lies there. I can provide more details if needed.
Any help appreciated
Tried tf.ensure_shape with tf.py_function, however it did not help
